# Jquery Mobile 1.4 cordova phonegap 3 iOS 7 event trigger fires twice on real device

Tags: events, jquery-mobile, cordova

Both solutions

```
$(document).off().on("click", "#myButton", function(event) {
    console.log('hello');            
});
```

and

```
$(document).off("click").on("click", "#myButton", function(event) {
    console.log('hello');          
});
```

not working. Any idas?

Comment: `$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page_id", function () { $(element).on("click", function () { //code }); });` try this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try

```
$("#myButton").off("click").on("click",function(event){
    console.log("test");
    event.preventDefault();
    even.stopPropagation();
    return(false);
});
```